# Android: Retrieve changes from the database

Tags: android, codeigniter, android-studio, retrofit

I am currently working on an android + website project using retrofit and codeigniter (with RESTFUL server). Basically, the user(android) can make request and the administrator(website) can accept/ reject that request. how can I make the android to recieve those updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create project with Google's Firebase Realtime Database [here](https://firebase.google.com/?&gclid=CjwKCAjwnrjrBRAMEiwAXsCc4wzmImyKiQLfyLniF9O5CGKMRUs7Mpf_evlKIPF2NzH3yBQxb0uAkBoCjwwQAvD_BwE).

You can set listeners for this for both - web and Android app. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) for details. Every time when the user sends request you can set a value with a unique id to the firebase. The listeners inside Android app will notify admin. And vice versa - if admin accepts the request (another value to the database) - web app will response.

You can also use WebSockets. https://dev.to/medaymentn/creating-a-realtime-chat-app-with-android--nodejs-and-socketio-4o55

Comment: Is there any alternative that will allow me to this while not connected on the internet?